# Can't link domain name to IP (Nothing displays)

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy

I have bought a domain  (http://qify.app) on google Domains
When opening Chromium / Firefox I don't have any thing coming out of it (`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`).

My current setup:

- An EC2 AWS machine running my nodeJS backend on port 3000 (localhost)
- A nGinx reverse proxy to redirect all inbound port 80 to 3000 (the backend) current nginx config: at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
server {
   listen         80 default_server;
   listen         [::]:80 default_server;
   server_name    localhost;
   root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
  location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

Also I can `curl 15.237.134.217` just as much as `curl qify.app` (and get the correct html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
...
</html>
```

Final nginx version (working for me, I needed two server blocks)

```
server {
   listen               443 ssl http2 ipv6only=off;
   server_name          qify.app;

   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/archive/qify.app/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/archive/qify.app/privkey.pem;

   ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;

   keepalive_timeout    70;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}

server { # Redirects all port 80 to 443 (with a 301 redirect)
   listen [::]:80 http2 ipv6only=off;
   server_name qify.app www.qify.app;
   return 301 https://qify.app$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .app TLD has a baked-in HSTS policy to always use HTTPS on any .app domain. Both Chrome and Firefox, along with several other browsers, include .app in their preloaded HSTS policy list. This means that these browsers will always lead with https on port 443. See https://blog.google/technology/developers/introducing-app-more-secure-home-apps-web/ as a reference to this https requirement.

The nginx config file you showed indicates that it is only listening on port 80. This is why the `curl http://qify.app` works, since it uses port 80, and doesn't have the preloaded HSTS list that those web browsers do.

Generate a certificate for your domain, and configure nginx to listen on port 443, and your browsers will be able to access it that way.